# backpropagation algorithm in matlab

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, backpropagation

I'm writing a back propagation algorithm in matlab. But I can not get to write a good solution. I read a book Haykin and read some topics in Internet, how make it other people. I understand from door to door this algorithm in theory, but I have a much of error in practice. I have a NaN in my code.
You can see here.

I'm trying classification some points on plate. These are three ellipses, which are placed one inside the other.

I wrote this function. The second layer learn, but first layer dont learn.

```
function [E, W_1, W_2, B_1, B_2, X_3] = update(W_1, W_2, B_1, B_2, X_1, T, alpha)

    V_1 = W_1 * X_1 + B_1;
    X_2 = tansig(V_1);
    V_2 = W_2 * X_2 + B_2;
    X_3 = tansig(V_2);

    E = 1 / 2 * sum((T - X_3) .^ 2);
    dE = (T - X_3);

    for j = 1 : size(X_2, 1)
        delta_2_sum = 0;
        for i = 1 : size(X_3, 1)
            delta_2 = dE(i, 1) * dtansig(1, V_2(i, 1) );

            W_2_tmp(i, j) = W_2(i, j) - alpha * delta_2 * X_2(j, 1);
            B_2_tmp(i, 1) = B_2(i, 1) - alpha * delta_2;
        end;
    end;

    for k = 1 : size(X_1, 1)
        for j = 1 : size(X_2, 1)
            delta_2_sum = 0;
            for i = 1 : size(X_3, 1)
                delta_2 = dE(i, 1) * dtansig(1, V_2(i, 1) );
                delta_2_sum = delta_2_sum + W_2(i, j) * delta_2;
            end;
            delta_1 = delta_2_sum * dtansig(1, V_1(j, 1) );

            W_1_tmp(j, k) = W_1(j, k) - alpha * delta_1 * X_1(k, 1);
            B_1_tmp(j, 1) = B_1(j, 1) - alpha * delta_1;
        end;
    end;

    if (min(W_1) < -10000 )
        X = 1;
    end;

    B_1 = B_1_tmp;
    B_2 = B_2_tmp;

    W_1 = W_1_tmp
    W_2 = W_2_tmp;

end
```

I wrote another variant code. And this code don't work. I calculated this code with 1-dimensional vector as input and as output. And I don't have truth result.
What can I do?
I use matlab nntool interface. But my backprop was written my hand.
How I can testing my code?

function [net] = backProp(net, epoch, alpha)

```
for u = 1 : epoch % Число эпох
    for p = 1 : size(net.userdata{1, 1}, 2)
        % Учим по всем элементам выборки
        [~, ~, ~, De, Df, f] = frontProp(net, p, 1);
        for l = size(net.LW, 1) : -1 : 1 % Обходим слои
            if (size(net.LW, 1) == l )
                delta{l} = De .* Df{l};
            else
                % size(delta{l + 1})
                % size(net.LW{l + 1})
                delta{l} = Df{l} .* (delta{l + 1}' * net.LW{l + 1} )';
            end;
            if (l == 1)
                net.IW{l} + alpha * delta{l} * f{l}'
                net.IW{l} = net.IW{l} + alpha * delta{l} * f{l}';
            else
                net.LW{l} + alpha * delta{l} * f{l}'
                net.LW{l} = net.LW{l} + alpha * delta{l} * f{l}';
            end;

        end;
    end;
end;
```

end

Comment: first simplify those for loops by matrix multiplication. the same way you did for V_1 and V_2 you can do for dW and dB. Secondly you can remove B and just use W, by increasing the dimension of W by 1 (initialized as the remain W), and increasing the dimension of X_1 and X_2 by one with the value of 1. Then errors will be easier to spot

Comment: Guys, I had 1-dimensional vector as input and 1-dimension vector as output to check my calculations program and hand job calculations. All the results are the same. I don't know where is my mistake.